# No sound in Ubuntu-Budgie 18.04 (ASUS TUF FX 505GD)

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-budgie

I have recently installed UBUNTU BUDGIE 18.04 LTS

The audio worked fine for a couple of days but now suddenly the audio is not working.

I tried all the generic methods listed such reinstalling alsamixer, but it didn't work out for me.

Also in most answers alsamixer has multiple devices, whereas I get only s/pdif

Alsamixer screenshot

[image]

I audio control settings I get Options of mechanical and analog output but no option of default speaker

Sound COntrol settings

[image]